# Convert nested JSON file to CSV in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a json file which contains nested keys and values.My requirement is to have the data in csv format and the csv file should contain below details

```
name title emails updatTime roles
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import csv
with open ("D:\Python_Tolusko/IICS_Users.json") as file:
        data=json.load(file)

fname='D:\Python_Tolusko/output.csv'

with open(fname,"w") as file:
        csv_file=csv.writer(file)
        csv_file.writerow(["name","title","emails","updateTime","roles"])
        for item in data:
                csv_file.writerow([item['name'],item['title'],item['emails'],item['updateTime'],item['roles']['name']])
                #rec=(value for value in data.roles.name())
                #csv_file.writerow(rec)
```

However on running the code I am getting below error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e810dd9e7ace> in <module>
     11         csv_file.writerow(["name","title","emails","updateTime","roles"])
     12         for item in data:
---> 13                 csv_file.writerow([item['name'],item['title'],item['emails'],item['updateTime'],item['roles']['name']])
     14                 #rec=(value for value in data.roles.name())
     15                 #csv_file.writerow(rec)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I tried updating the integer in

```
csv_file.writerow([item['name'],item['title'],item['emails'],item['updateTime'],item['roles'][1]])

 File "<ipython-input-3-6e39021aca6a>", line 13
    csv_file.writerow([item['name'],item['title'],item['emails'],item['updateTime'],item['roles'][1])
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please find the below JSON output

```
[
  {
    "@type": "user",
    "id": "017Q3A0300000000000C",
    "name": "Abc",
    "updateTime": "2021-04-07T09:54:06.000Z",
    "title": "Dev",
    "password": "********",
    "phone": "9999999999",
    "emails": "abc@gmail.com",
    "roles": [
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "MDM Business User",
        "description": "Role used for MDM C360 Business Application runtime."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Customer 360 Data Steward",
        "description": "MDM Customer 360 Data Steward"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Data Viewer",
        "description": "Role used for granting access for data"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Designer",
        "description": "Role for creating assets, tasks, and processes. Can configure connections, schedules, and runtime environments. Has access to the Application Integration Console."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Business Manager",
        "description": "Role used for business managers"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "MDM Designer",
        "description": "MDM Designer"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "Role for performing administrative tasks for an organization. Has full access to all licensed services."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Deployer",
        "description": "Role used by deployer"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Operator",
        "description": "Role used for monitoring execution environments"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Monitor",
        "description": "Role used for application monitor"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Customer 360 Manager",
        "description": "MDM Customer 360 Manager"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Data Preview",
        "description": "Role to preview data"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Service Consumer",
        "description": "Role for running tasks, taskflows, and processes."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Customer 360 Analyst",
        "description": "MDM Customer 360 Analyst"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Data Integration Task Executor",
        "description": "Role to run Data Integration tasks"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@type": "user",
    "id": "017Q3A03000000000002",
    "name": "Admin",
    "updateTime": "2021-05-28T12:51:44.000Z",
    "title": "Admin",
    "password": "********",
    "phone": "9999999999",
    "emails": "Admin@123.com",

    "roles": [
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Designer",
        "description": "Role for creating assets, tasks, and processes. Can configure connections, schedules, and runtime environments. Has access to the Application Integration Console."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@type": "user",
    "id": "017Q3A0300000000000G",
    "orgId": "017Q3A",
    "name": "Xyz",
    "title": "Developer",
    "password": "********",
    "phone": "9999999999",
    "emails": "xyz@123.com",
    
    "roles": [
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Customer 360 Manager",
        "description": "MDM Customer 360 Manager"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Data Preview",
        "description": "Role to preview data"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Designer",
        "description": "Role for creating assets, tasks, and processes. Can configure connections, schedules, and runtime environments. Has access to the Application Integration Console."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Data Viewer",
        "description": "Role used for granting access for data"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Data Integration Task Executor",
        "description": "Role to run Data Integration tasks"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "Role for performing administrative tasks for an organization. Has full access to all licensed services."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Customer 360 Data Steward",
        "description": "MDM Customer 360 Data Steward"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Service Consumer",
        "description": "Role for running tasks, taskflows, and processes."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "MDM Designer",
        "description": "MDM Designer"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "MDM Business User",
        "description": "Role used for MDM C360 Business Application runtime."
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Customer 360 Analyst",
        "description": "MDM Customer 360 Analyst"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Monitor",
        "description": "Role used for application monitor"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Business Manager",
        "description": "Role used for business managers"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Deployer",
        "description": "Role used by deployer"
      },
      {
        "@type": "role",
        "name": "Operator",
        "description": "Role used for monitoring execution environments"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

PLease help how I can have desired role for the corresponding user

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: for the version where you put the integer, you're missing a ] before the )

Comment: Thanks for you comment.My bad I missed it,i updated it and now it gives below error---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---> 13                 csv_file.writerow([item['name'],item['title'],item['emails'],item['updateTime'],item['roles'][1]])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Update your question - presumably for this entry `item['roles']` only has one entry, i.e. index 0.

Comment: Initially i tried with item['roles'] but in that case all the value which are couples with roles were coming so thought to update it with index but with index 0 as well it was giving index out of range error.

Comment: perhaps roles is an empty list - IDK you will have to examine it  -it's your data!

Answer (score 0):

There are missing fields in your data, if they should be, I would suggest using `.get` option for dictionary

Something like that

```
jsonfile = open('data.json', 'r').read()
csvfile = open('data.csv', 'w', newline='')
rows = json.loads(jsonfile)
output = []
for row in rows:
    outrow = [row.get('name'),
              row.get('title'),
              row.get('emails'),
              row.get('updateTime'),
              row.get('roles')]
    output.append(outrow)
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerows(output)
```